# Disabling TRACE request method on Apache/2.0.52

Tags: apache, xss, trace, mod-rewrite

By default, Apache 2.0.52 will respond to any HTTP TRACE request that it receives. This is a potential security problem because it can allow certain types of XSS attacks. For details, see http://www.apacheweek.com/issues/03-01-24#news

I am trying to disable TRACE requests by following the instructions shown in the page linked to above. I added the following lines of code to my http.conf file, and restarted apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

However, when I send a TRACE request to my web server, it seems to ignore the rewrite rules and responds as if TRACE requests were still enabled.

For example:

```
[admin2@dedicated ~]$ telnet XXXX.com 80
Trying XXXX...
Connected to XXXX.com (XXXX).
Escape character is '^]'.
TRACE / HTTP/1.0
X-Test: foobar

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Jul 2009 17:33:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
Connection: close
Content-Type: message/http

TRACE / HTTP/1.0
X-Test: foobar

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The server should respond with 403 Forbidden. Instead, it echoes back my request with a 200 OK.

As a test, I changed the RewriteCond to %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET

When I do this, Apache correctly responds to all GET requests with 403 Forbidden. But when I change GET back to TRACE, it still lets TRACE requests through.

How can I get Apache to stop responding to TRACE requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to do it.

I had tried placing the block of rewrite directives in three places: in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` part of the httpd.conf file, at the top of my httpd.conf file, and in the /var/www/html/.htaccess file. None of these three methods worked.

Finally, however, I tried putting the block of code in `<VirtualHost *:80>` part of my httpd.conf. For some reason, it works when it is placed. there.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions require:

TraceEnable Off

Comment: Apache 2.0.52 does not support the TraceEnable directive

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, that works in your VirtualHost block. As you didn't show httpd.conf I can't say why your initial attempt didn't work - it's context-sensitive.

It failed in the  because it's not really relevant there, that's generally for access control. If it didn't work in the .htaccess it's likely that apache wasn't looking for it (you can use AllowOverride to enable them).